# Button overlay is showing over Button Text, SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My `Button` requires a couple overlays to get the style it needs (stroke, shadow etc).

However these overlays then go over the `Button` text.

[image]

View:

```
struct ProfileTest: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
        }){
            HStack {
                Text("OFFLINE")
                    .font(.custom("Seravek-Bold", size: 25))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            }
        }.padding(EdgeInsets(top: 12, leading: 15, bottom: 12, trailing: 15))
        .cornerRadius(50)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50)
                .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1)
        )
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50)
                .fill(Color.red)
                .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(1), radius: 1)
        )
        .opacity(0.7)
        .padding(.bottom, 100)
        .padding(.bottom, 20)
    }
}
```

How can I adjust my view so that the blue text shows *above* the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom `ButtonStyle`.

1. Create your own shape and add `.overlay(configuration.label)` on top of it:

```
struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .hidden()
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 12, leading: 15, bottom: 12, trailing: 15))
            .cornerRadius(50)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50)
                    .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1)
            )
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50)
                    .fill(Color.red)
                    .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(1), radius: 1)
            )
            .opacity(0.7)
            .overlay(configuration.label)
            .padding(.bottom, 100)
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
    }
}
```

You can also use `configuration.isPressed` to customise your label behaviour on button press.

2. Apply it to your `Button`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {}) {
            HStack {
                Text("OFFLINE")
                    .font(.custom("Seravek-Bold", size: 25))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            }
        }
        .buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle())
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes Button take up the full width and height - any way to control that without settings fixed dimensions?

Comment: Thankyou. The only downside is it loses the `active` state - where the button opacity decreases when it's pressed down. Not sure if there's any way to solve that using this method though

Comment: @Zorgan You may use `configuration.isPressed` to detect if a button is pressed or not and then act accordingly.